# DeprecationWarning: While preprocessing data in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

```
df:

      cont1     cont2     cont3     cont4     cont5     cont6     cont7  
  0  0.726300  0.245921  0.187583  0.789639  0.310061  0.718367  0.335060   
  1  0.330514  0.737068  0.592681  0.614134  0.885834  0.438917  0.436585   
  2  0.261841  0.358319  0.484196  0.236924  0.397069  0.289648  0.315545   
  3  0.321594  0.555782  0.527991  0.373816  0.422268  0.440945  0.391128   
  4  0.273204  0.159990  0.527991  0.473202  0.704268  0.178193  0.247408 

Code:

from sklearn import preprocessing
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()

for each_column in df.columns:
    df[each_column].reshape(1, -1) #suggested solution
    df[each_column] = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(df[each_column])


Warning:

validation.py:395: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as 
data is   deprecated in 0.17 and will raise ValueError in 0.19. 
Reshape your data   either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data 
has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
DeprecationWarning)
```

Please suggest me on what is the mistake, is it because I am not passing the data to the preprocessor as numpy array?

I have tried the suggested solutions still getting the same warning.

Answer (score 0):

The deprecation warning is telling you what to do.

Use either `df[each_column].reshape(-1, 1)` or `df[each_column].reshape(1, -1)`

If you read the documentation for `Series` you'll also see that Pandas uses `ndarray` internally.

Comment: After reshaping can i use the code what I have written to get the transformation work?

Comment: Sorry, I mean that you need to pass that in to `min_max_scaler.fit_transform`. I.e. `min_max_scaler.fit_transform(df[each_column].reshape(1, -1))`.

Answer (score 0):

When something is deprecated, it means that it is no longer planned to be supported in future versions. As the message explains, passing a 1D array will start giving you an error in version 0.19. If you're writing new code, you should try to avoid using deprecated functions, and follow the recommendation of the message (use the reshape method for arrays).

Whether you call `df[each_column].reshape(-1, 1)` or `df[each_column].reshape(1, -1)` depends on the nature of the data contained in `df[each_column]`, as explained by the deprecation warning message. It'll turn your 1D array into either a "column" or a "row" vector.